How can I assert the order of network requests when multiple useEffect are used?
I am creating a website to track daily food intake. On this webpage I have a cache, which is simply a string key (A date) that maps into an object.
const progressCache = useRef<Record<string, MacroNutrientProgress>>({});

I two useEffects. The first one is the make a GET request to retrieve the current state of the progress and attempts to populate the cache.
    useEffect(() => {
        getMacroNutrientProgressOnDate(selectedDate)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                progressCache.current[getCacheKey(selectedDate)] = {
                    currentCalories: result.current_calories
                }

                setCurrentCalories(result.current_calories)
            }
        })

I then have a second useEffect to make a POST, in order to create an entry for that particular date. I know it's unique if their is no entry in the Cache for that particular day.
    const isInitialRender = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        /*
            Do not make an immediate request to store the progress on an unchanged date.

            Only when any modifications have been made, store the user data. 
        */
        if (isInitialRender.current) {
            isInitialRender.current = false;
        } else {
            const cacheKey = getCacheKey(selectedDate);

            if (getCacheKey(selectedDate) in progressCache) {
                console.log("Do a PATCH");
            } else {
                createMacroNutrientProgressOnDate(selectedDate, currentCalories)
                .then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        progressCache.current[cacheKey] = {
                            currentCalories
                        }
                    }
                })   
            }
        }
    }, [currentCalories])

My database has a constraint that user_id and date are unique. Multiple instances cannot be created. The problem I am running into is that the GET is not finished and does not populate the cache,
if (getCacheKey(selectedDate) in progressCache)

will never evaluate to true and I get an error because the row for that date already exists. I need to make use the useEffect for the POST is only performed after the GET during initial rendering, afterwards, they should only be called when the dependencies have changed.
How can this be done?

There seems to be a lot going on here, but if I understand your question correctly, when this Component mounts, you want to make a GET request (getMacroNutrientProgressOnDate) and when that Promise is fulfilled, make a second (POST) request (createMacroNutrientProgressOnDate) if there is not an entry in the cache for the selectedDate. Is that correct?

Very close. When the component is mounted, make a GET to check if I have any data on that Date to determine if the date can be pre-populated with data. I don't want to make an immediate request to match a POST/PATCH unless changes have been made so reduce unnecessary database store. So, my dependency for the PATCH/POST are all current/goal macronutrients. My GET is on the date change. The issue is during initial render it calls both useEffect and I get an annoying code condition, whereas I don't want to call POST/PATCH during the initial load as I don't want to store anything yet.

"unless changes have been made"
Meaning changes to the value of currentCalories should trigger the POST/PATCH... What is the initial value of currentCalories, and are we only concerned with changes to that value based on the results of getMacroNutrientProgressOnDate? The likely solution is to chain the two Promises (and remove the second useEffect call), or refine the conditional logic in your second useEffect (if the value of currentCalories is updated elsewhere in the code which you're also trying to capture here). But it's hard to say for sure without a [mcve]
